# How can I check a specific column in an Eloquent query result?

Tags: php, laravel

I have free bonus system on my web.  In this system. There are 2 tables 1 "deposit " and other is plan. In deposit there is column "plan_id" I want if user has record with plan_d 8 then he should alert message ." You already subscribe free bonus"

I tried following.

```
$sit = Deposit::where('plan_id', Plan::id)->first();

if ($sit == 8) {
    session()->flash('message', 'Please Add fund at least once to withdraw life time.');
    Session::flash('type', 'warning');
    Session::flash('title', 'warning');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear

Comment: The question you've asked in the title, and the content of the question are wildly different. I've tidied up your code and corrected the title.

Comment: `dd($sit)` and you'll check it is not integer (i.e. 8). It should be object.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get check if user has deposit with plan id 8 or not for that you need user id. I assuming your deposit table also has `user_id`, your query will look like this

```
$sit = Deposit::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('plan_id','8')->first();

if ($sit) {
    session()->flash('message', 'Please Add fund at least once to withdraw life time.');
    Session::flash('type', 'warning');
    Session::flash('title', 'warning');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically checking that a model instance equals 8.

The following will return an instance of `Deposit` or null;

```
$sit = Deposit::where('plan_id', Plan::id)->first();
```

So your if statement should be;

```
if ($sit && $sit->plan_id == 8) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Undefined class constant 'id'

Comment: You haven't created a constant in `Plan` called `id`.

Comment: Plan_id is column inside deposit table

Comment: I want to replace e.g auth::user()->Id with deposit->plan_id

Comment: In your code, you're doing `Plan::id` which doesn't exist. I don't know what your issue is, but it sounds like you're just getting more and more errors.

Comment: Simple words. I want to know how to get plan_id present inside deposit table. And in deposit table plan_id is coming from plan table

Comment: I assume, that `plan_id` can be null. If that's the case, you want to do `Deposit::whereNotNull('plan_id')`. I think you may need to read the documentation on Eloquent and Laravel queries. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries